# Android Studio: HorizontalView

Tags: java, android, image, horizontal-scrolling

Have a horizontalView containing an image that I would like to be scrollable from left to right. The image does scroll but contains padding around the image and I would like it to fill the entire screen. How can this be achieved?

[image]

The image has grey space all around it, my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_rear_gunner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:focusable="true"
tools:context="com.example.mr_br.ibcc_bomber_command.rear_gunner">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_scroll_2"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_centerVertical="true"

/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the android:scaleType="centerCrop" in ImageView to make the image to fit entirely over the screen.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: pleasure is all mine